# Existential proof with number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

If $a$ is not a multiple of a prime $p$, then prove that there is an integer $b$ such that $p^b-1$ is a multiple of $a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the class of $p$ in the multiplicative monoid of residue classes modulo $a$. The assumption that $p \nmid a$ implies that $\gcd(p, a) = 1$, hence the class of $p$ is invertible modulo $a$.

Can you finish from here?

Comment: What is a monoid?

Comment: I am just referring to the residue classes modulo $a$ with respect to multiplication.